# Unlock device and swich to other screen

Tags: android

I am trying to write a simple code to switch activity when unlock the device (if app is open) for that I have to switch another activity I have tried this code.But even that code it shows the current screen for a fraction of second. what should I do.

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
   // This is the second main Layout after main layout (which has  
  //  background image)
    mainLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    super.onResume();
    checkActivity();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SimpleChatMainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   //Visible after 1 second
                    mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
  // Some code

}
```

Comment: if you just want to change the background image then you should try to change the back ground images instead of making it visible and invisible, plus i need to look at the both xml and activity code to tell a proper solution

Comment: "shows the current screen for a fraction of second"....you are using `postDelayed` with 1 Second, so it logical....from the docs (for the delay time):`The delay (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed.`

Comment: and if you want to switch activity, why you are setting the layout to `VISIBLE`and `INVISIBLE`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Opiatefuchs and Anders, I don't want to show my current screen when unlock even for a fraction of second actually we are making highly secure App and we want to switch the user to the login screen but even set the delay for 1 second it's show the last screen (some time not always) for a fraction of second